# having problem when I want to put image inside input

Tags: html, css

why I can't put an image inside input with positions???

input right now:

[image]

```
<div class="password-container">
    <input class="main-input" id="password-input" type="password" minlength="8" title="Must contain at least 8 or more characters" placeholder="رمز عبور" required>
<img class="password-show-icon" src="Eye.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

```
.main-input {
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.040);
    background-color: #f1f1f1; */

    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #00000025;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 17px 30px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 60%;
    direction: rtl;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: relative;
}

.password-show-icon {
    position: absolute;
}
```

please help me! I really need help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick

```css
  .password-container {
    position: relative;
  }


  .main-input {
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.040);
    background-color: #f1f1f1; */

    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #00000025;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 17px 30px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 60%;
    direction: rtl;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .password-show-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<label for="password-input" class="password-container">
  <input class="main-input" id="password-input" type="password" minlength="8" title="Must contain at least 8 or more characters" placeholder="رمز عبور" required>
  <img class="password-show-icon" src="Eye.svg" alt="eye">
</label>
```

Comment: but with top and left in responsive, it shows outside of the input

Comment: @Mazdak well you can adjust it as you wish, but on my code snippet it always inside of input no matter what page width. Maybe you haven't used whole code as I provided or you putting something else inside label tag too

Comment: So, how can I fix this, so that at least it doesn't come out of the input?

Comment: sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: you have to provide example of what seams to be the problem

Comment: I don't like to show icon outside the input when the screen resized

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to solve my problem

Comment: I don't get it, how the hell it get outside if I provided you with solution that keeps it inside, unless you show me the updated code and screenshot of the result I don't know how to help you

Comment: ok thanks again I try to solve my problem

Comment: have you tried to use provided code or not?

Comment: yes, I tried it.......

Comment: and? could you post update on your question with new code, and new screenshot?

Comment: no thanks I'm trying

Comment: whatever man, you probably missed something while using solution

Answer (score 0):

Please, check, I just replace the eye icon with an online image CDN, to show it.

```css
.password-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.main-input {
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.040);
    background-color: #f1f1f1; */

    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #00000025;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 17px 35px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 60%;
    direction: rtl;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: relative;
}

.password-show-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="password-container">
    <input class="main-input" id="password-input" type="password" minlength="8" title="Must contain at least 8 or more characters" placeholder="رمز عبور" required>
<img class="password-show-icon" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/businessman-character-avatar-isolated_24877-60111.jpg?w=2000" alt="" width="20" height="20">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one way to accomplish this, involving putting both elements into a contiainer, and just placing one absolutely to the top right.

```js
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);

const input = $("input");

$(".show-password").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const newType = input.type == "text" ? "password" : "text";
  input.type = newType;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  --width: 100px;
  --height: 40px;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

input {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.show-password {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  --size: 2rem;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  user-select: none;
}


.material-symbols-outlined {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.show-password:hover .material-symbols-outlined {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" value="test" />
  <div class="show-password">
    <div class="material-symbols-outlined">
      visibility
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```